# Spinner in progress dialogue is not rotating

Tags: android

I am using Progress dialogue on loading a listview. But the spinner in progress dialogue is not rotating (animating).

In `doInBackground` function, I am calling a webservice function, could that be an issue ?

My code is:

```
private class loadMoreListView extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // Showing progress dialog before sending http request
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(secondPageActivity.this);
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    // Calling the Webservice function
                }
            });
            return (null);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            // closing progress dialog
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `setProgresStyle()` method and you're done  why? because you already set it to indeterminate

Answer (score 0):

If you are using custom progress dialog then you have to use

```
pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
```

But if you are using default progress dialog then no need of this line. Remove it and just set message and it spins.